# New column in a df based on "events" in previous rows

Tags: r

I have a football/soccer chance creation dataframe where for each shot I want to add the gamestate ie if the team that is taking the shot is -1, 0, +1, +2....

The dataframe can be simplified as follow and the last column `df$Gamestate` is what I want to create:

```
df<-data.frame(Gameid=c("123","123","123","123","324","324","324","324"), 
Hometeam=c("A","A","A","A","C","C","C","C")
Awayteam=c("B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D")               
Time=c(12,23,34,64,2,24,28,36), 
Team=c("A","B","A","B","C","D","D","C"),
Goal=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
Gamestate=c(0,-1,1,-2,0,0,1,-2))
```

Here, in plain english, the first shot of the game 123 is taken by team A at the 12th minute so game state is zero, and team A scores. Then team B shots but has conceded a goal so gamestate is -1 etc...

EDIT:
My idea would be to create `df$Scorehometeam` and `df$Scoreawayteam` to keep track of the score for each event, and populate `df$gamestate` based on who is taking the shot. Just don't know how to cope with `Gameid` and `Time`

Comment: And what do you want to calculate? Do you have a formula in mind? Could you write pseudo-code of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to calculate the gamestate column but although I can formulate it in word, I struggle to put it in formula or pseudo code yet.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how do you calculate the gamestate

Comment: If score between Team A and Team B is 2-3 then gamestate for team A is -1 and Team B is +1. Etc.

Comment: this is still confusing to me, if in gameid 123 two goals are scored by team A the gamestate for team B is -2 and 1 for team A. If it is 2-0 then B = -2 but why is A +1?

Comment: No,  if two goals are scored by team A and then team A takes a shot, gamestate is 2 for Team A, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best solution but it works:

```
get_score<-function(x,y,z){
    n<-length(x)
    s<-rep(0,n)
    for (i in 1:n){
      s[i]=sum(x[1:(i-1)]*(y[1:(i-1)]==y[i])*(z[1:(i-1)]==z[i]))-sum(x[1:(i-1)]*(y[1:(i-1)]!=y[i])*(z[1:(i-1)]==z[i])) 
    }
    s[1]=0
    s
 }
dt$score<-get_score(dt$Goal,dt$Team,dt$Gameid)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get : `Error in s[i] = sum(x[1:(i - 1)] * (y[1:(i - 1)] == y[i]) * (z[1:(i -  : 
  object 's' not found`

Comment: Sorry, added `s<-rep(0,n)`

Comment: We are getting there ! Do you know how to ensure now, that it also takes the df$time into account? Should I just sort the dataframe by gameid then time?

Comment: Yes, this is why it is not the best solution :) But if you sort data before running it will work.

Comment: Yes it did work after sorting, that's fine with me, two extra lines of code... Thanks a lot, it was a tricky one!